# Using externalized properties file in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to execute environment specific **application-{PROFILE}.properties** file (which I have set in my environment variable) in my application. So let us say I have environment defined as "prod", so the application should use application-prod.properties file.
Kindly suggest me how to achieve this. Thank you in advance.

Edit 1: I am using ***java -jar MyApp.jar*** to run. And suppose I have 4 application.properties files in my app, and I want my app to use the application-dev.properties file ( here **dev** is defined in my environment variable)

Edit 2: I can't use **spring.profiles.active** **in application.properties** file, because in that case I will have to change every time I will run my jar in different env, let us say dev,uat and prod.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Answer (score 0):

Run with following maven command.

```
mvn clean install -P<PROFILE_NAME>
```

It will use properties file based on the profile.

Comment: I have application-prod.properties file, tried running 
mvn clean install -P "application-prod.properties" 
but it is saying The requested profile "application-prod.properties" could not be activated because it does not exist.